# How can I using Class::Function(params) without static

Tags: php

* Sorry, I am learning English now and my English is still not so good. Please understand my situation.

As far as I know, Static is required to use like Class::Function(params);
Like this one.

```
class Foo {
    static function Bar($msg){
        echo $msg;
    }
}
```

There is one file in XE(is CMS developed in Korea).
(XE Official Site : http://www.xpressengine.com/?l=en)

Of course, This is a summary of real file

```
<?php

/**
 * Manages Context such as request arguments/environment variables
 * It has dual method structure, easy-to use methods which can be called as self::methodname(),and methods called with static object.
 */

class Context
{
   /**
    * codes after <body>
    * @var string
    */
   public $body_header = NULL;

   /**
    * returns static context object (Singleton). It's to use Context without declaration of an object
    *
    * @return object Instance
    */
   function &getInstance()
   {
      static $theInstance = null;
      if(!$theInstance)
      {
         $theInstance = new Context();
      }
      return $theInstance;
   }

   /**
    * Add html code after <body>
    *
    * @param string $header Add html code after <body>
    */
   function addBodyHeader($header)
   {
      is_a($this, 'Context') ? $self = $this : $self = self::getInstance();
      $self->body_header .= "\n" . $header;
   }
}
```

This is the comment at the top of this file.

> It has dual method structure, easy-to use methods which can be called
>   as self::methodname(),and methods called with static object.

In this comment, It can use Class::Function() and I have been using in XE.
But it don't tell how they make. How can I make like it?

**Edit1 :**

The file's name is Context.class.php and It is included in other files.

```
<?php
    require(_XE_PATH_ . 'classes/context/Context.class.php');
    Context::addBodyHeader("Some Codes");
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking because `self::getInstance()` calls `getInstance` which is not a static method?

Comment: @kingkero No, "Context::addBodyHeader(...)" can use in XE's other file. And It is not static function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this comment, It can use Class::Function() and I have been using in
>   XE. But it don't tell how they make. How can I make like it?
>   The `::` is called the [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

They make it as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    public static function saySomething() {
        echo 'hello';
    }
     public function sayHello() {
        echo 'hello';
    }

    public function helloSay() {
        self::sayHello();
    }
}
```

`MyClass::saySomething();`

`MyClass::sayHello();`

`MyClass::helloSay();`

They all output: `hello`

Comment: But, "Context::addBodyHeader(...)" can use in XE.
And It is not static function.

Comment: please, look "without static" in question title

Comment: Updated. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: But, "MyClass::sayHello()" cause an Strict Standards Error. Then.... the source in the question will cause Strict Standards error too?

Comment: Oh! I find this code in other file.
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_WARNING ^ E_STRICT)
I think the code in the question will cause error, but it is not print by this error_reporting code.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well in this case they use `self`, which doesn't need the static, you can compare `self::` to `$this->`, just that `self::` also works for static functions.

Maybe [the manual](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) helps you

Comment: But, "Context::addBodyHeader(...)" can use in XE.
And It is not static function.

Comment: please, look "without static" in question title

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but you can declare "static" in php `public static function methodName()` and then call the function with `Class::Method()` You can also check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for more data on static.

**EDIT:**

This is from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from
>   within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object
>   (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another
>   object, if the method is called statically from the context of a
>   secondary object).

So basically you can do this (call class method static way).

Comment: But, "Context::addBodyHeader(...)" can use in XE.
And It is not static function.

Comment: please, look "without static" in question title